# How to correctly pass firewall rules to the google-terraform-network module?

Tags: firewall, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I want to create a network using the `google-terraform-network` module. Additionally, I want to pass the firewall rules I made as a parameter to the module so that the created network contains these two rules.

When I pass the firewall rules directly, i.e.:

```
firewall_rules = [google_compute_firewall.allow_ssh, google_compute_firewall.allow_http]
```

I receive the following error:  `The given value is not suitable for module.vpc.module.firewall_rules.var.rules declared at .terraform/modules/vpc/modules/firewall-rules/variables.tf:27,1-17: element 0: attribute "log_config": object required.`.

On the other hand, when I pass the `self_link`, i.e.:

```
firewall_rules = [google_compute_firewall.allow_ssh.self_link, google_compute_firewall.allow_http.self_link]
```

I get numerous errors of the following form:

```
 Error: Invalid function argument
│ 
│   on .terraform/modules/vpc/main.tf line 70, in locals:
│   70:       deny                    = lookup(f, "deny", [])
│ 
│ Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first argument.
```

Here's the complete `main.tf`:

```
provider "google" {
  project = var.project
  region  = var.region
  zone    = var.zone
}

// firewall rule to allow ssh
resource "google_compute_firewall" "allow_ssh" {
  name    = "allow-ssh"
  network = var.network_name

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["22"]
  }

  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}

// firewall rule to allow http
resource "google_compute_firewall" "allow_http" {
  name    = "allow-http"
  network = var.network_name

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["80"]
  }

  source_ranges = [""]
}

module "vpc" {
    source  = "terraform-google-modules/network/google"
    version = "~> 7.0"

    project_id   = var.project
    network_name = var.network_name
    routing_mode = "GLOBAL"

    subnets = [
        {
            subnet_name   = var.subnet_name
            subnet_ip     = var.subnet_ip
            subnet_region = var.region
        },
    ]

    firewall_rules = [google_compute_firewall.allow_ssh.self_link, google_compute_firewall.allow_http.self_link]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution. The `firewall_rules` parameter demands a list of objects that follow a specific structure. Adding the following variable and assigning it to the `firewall_rules` parameter solves the problem:

```
variable "rules" {
    description = "List of rule definitions"
    default     = [
        {
        name                    = "allow-ssh-ingress"
        direction               = "INGRESS"
        ranges                  = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
        allow = [{
            protocol = "tcp"
            ports    = ["22"]
        }]
        deny = []
        log_config = {
            metadata = "INCLUDE_ALL_METADATA"
        }
        },

        {
            name                    = "allow-http-ingress"
            direction               = "INGRESS"
            ranges                  = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
            allow = [{
                protocol = "tcp"
                ports    = ["80"]
            }]
            deny = []
            log_config = {
                metadata = "INCLUDE_ALL_METADATA"
            }
        }
    ]

    type = list(object({
        name                    = string
        description             = optional(string)
        direction               = optional(string)
        priority                = optional(number)
        ranges                  = optional(list(string))
        source_tags             = optional(list(string))
        source_service_accounts = optional(list(string))
        target_tags             = optional(list(string))
        target_service_accounts = optional(list(string))
        allow = optional(list(object({
            protocol = string
            ports    = optional(list(string))
        })))
        deny = optional(list(object({
            protocol = string
            ports    = optional(list(string))
        })))
        log_config = optional(object({
            metadata = string
        }))
    }))
}
```

Afterwards:

```
firewall_rules = var.rules
```